# Eslint force to consume return values

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, eslint

I am looking for a typescript or eslint rule I can use to force using return values from functions. Eg

```
const getNum = () => 12
```

The rule should allow me to call it and store the value like

```
const a = getNum()
```

But I should not be able to do

```
getNum()
```

I am currently experimenting with libraries like neverthrow or ts-results and at this moment if I return a result<ok, err> the consumer is still able to call a function without handling errors, especially when the ok part is just an success result.

Answer (score 0):

The rule that's closest to what you're looking for is [`no-unused-expressions`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions), but based on your question it seems like you're already aware of that rule. That webpage includes a rationale of why it allows something like `getNum()` on its own; a function might return a value while also having some side effects. Blanket disallowing calling functions without storing the result would end up with lots of code that looks like:

```
const unused = callForSideEffects();
// unused is... unused
```

This is wasteful (since you're storing a value that's not ever used) and confusing (why store a value if it's not ever used?)

Comment: I am more looking into a situation like this
```
const error = functionWithSideEffectsOrFail()
```
If I don't force myself to grab the error, I might fail silently